# Session hijacking solution fails for Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, session-cookies

To avoid session hijacking the following solution was implemented in the company where I work:

```
private static string secretKey = null;

/// <summary>
/// method to initialize our class when the page is initialized
/// </summary>
/// <param name="application"></param>
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
{
    //find out of we have a validation key, if we dont initialize it
    if (secretKey == null) secretKey = GetKey();

    //register event handlers for the BeginRequest and EndRequest events
    application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(onbeginRequest);
    application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(onendRequest);
}

public void Dispose() 
{ 
}

/// <summary>
/// method for handling the HttpApplication.BeginRequest event
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
public void onbeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the current Request
    HttpRequest currentRequest = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;

    //get the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie from the Request object
    HttpCookie requestCookie = RetrieveRequestCookie(currentRequest, "ASP.NET_SessionId");

    //check to see if the cookie exists (if == null)
    if (requestCookie != null)
    {
        //if the length is less than 24 we dont have a MAC so we need to throw an exception (our custom exception)
        if (requestCookie.Value.Length <= 24) throw new SessionerrorException("Invalid Session, Code 1");

        //get the session id
        string sessionID = requestCookie.Value.Substring(0, 24);

        //get the MAC
        string mac = requestCookie.Value.Substring(24);

        //create a new MAC based on the session id and some of the users info (user agent, etc)
        string macCompare = CreateMAC(sessionID, currentRequest.UserHostAddress, currentRequest.UserAgent, secretKey);

        //check to see if the MAC's match, if not we have a problem
        if (String.CompareOrdinal(mac, macCompare) != 0) throw new SessionerrorException("Invalid Session, Code 2");

        //set the cookies value to the session id
        requestCookie.Value = sessionID;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// method for handling the HttpApplication.EndRequest event
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
public void onendRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //capture the current request
    HttpRequest currentRequest = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;

    //get the session cookie
    HttpCookie sessionCookie = RetrieveResponseCookie(((HttpApplication)sender).Response, "ASP.NET_SessionId");

    //make sure the cookie isnt null
    if (sessionCookie != null)
    {
        //add our newly generated MAC to the cookie at the end of the request
        sessionCookie.Value += CreateMAC(sessionCookie.Value, currentRequest.UserHostAddress, currentRequest.UserAgent, secretKey);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// method for retrieving the Request cookies
/// </summary>
/// <param name="currentRequest"></param>
/// <param name="cookieName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private HttpCookie RetrieveRequestCookie(HttpRequest currentRequest, string cookieName)
{
    HttpCookieCollection cookieCollection = currentRequest.Cookies;
    return FindTheCookie(cookieCollection, cookieName);
}

/// <summary>
/// method for retrieving the Response cookies
/// </summary>
/// <param name="currentResponse"></param>
/// <param name="cookieName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private HttpCookie RetrieveResponseCookie(HttpResponse currentResponse, string cookieName)
{
    HttpCookieCollection cookies = currentResponse.Cookies;
    return FindTheCookie(cookies, cookieName);
}

/// <summary>
/// method for generating a new MAC for our session cookie
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">current session id</param>
/// <param name="ipAddress">ip address of the current Request</param>
/// <param name="userAgent">current user's User Agent</param>
/// <param name="validationKey">validation key from the web.config</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string CreateMAC(string id, string ipAddress, string userAgent, string validationKey)
{
    //create an instance of the StringBuilder with a max length of 512
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(id, 512);

    //append the first segment of the user's ip address to the string
    sb.Append(ipAddress.Substring(0, ipAddress.IndexOf('.', ipAddress.IndexOf('.') + 1)));

    //append the users User Agent to the string
    sb.Append(userAgent);

    using (HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(validationKey)))
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString())));
    }
}
```

The problem is that Google Chrome always happens the exception "Invalid Session, Code 1", but works perfectly in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Any idea what might be happening and how can I fix?

Comment: You should be able to debug and see why it is failing, no? Where exactly is it throwing the error? I see 2 spots with that same message. This also looks like it only works when the IP is different. What happens when people are connected to the same network i.e. at a coffee shop or public venue? EDIT: Why is `secretKey` static? That's probably a big issue there.... is it not specific to a session?

Comment: The error does not happen locally, the exception is thrown after "if (requestCookie.Value.Length <= 24)"

Comment: Is it every time or sometimes? Could it just be that someone has cookies blocked? I would expect to get a `null` back, but I could also see getting back an empty cookie.

Comment: what happens if you clear your cookies from firefox/IE?  Do they then have the same problem?

Comment: Tested in the office and at home on different computers, Chrome always fails, IE and Firefox always work even after clearing cookies.